# android intent to open data-roaming setting page ,does not work correctly.

Tags: android, roaming

I use the below code to open data-roaming setting page

```
f(bv<Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
            ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
            intent.setComponent(cName);
            startActivityForResult(intent,10);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(intent,10);
        }
```

and it works fine on the most of the device.but on some devices it opens the settings page but data roaming option is not available in that page.

Comment: The settings application keeps on changing according to the devices and the android OS so it can be possible that in some devices you will not the option all the time correctly it can be shifted on wifi section also.

Comment: Any help how to handle this all this.

Comment: In which devices you are facing issue?

Comment: Gionee E3 and LenovoA8000

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong settings pages are opened by the device when I fire the system intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480845/wrong-settings-pages-are-opened-by-the-device-when-i-fire-the-system-intent)

Comment: this must be happening for those samsung devices

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

It's working in my case using android 4.1.2

Comment: This intent forwards your app to roaming settings and data, but i if would like to go to Data Usage, how i achieve that?

Comment: @AlexSanchez this scenario is different from this one. ask a different question and provide me the link

Comment: @AlexSanchez may be [ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS) is what you are looking for :)

Comment: I dont think so.   dude :-|