# Wrong settings pages are opened by the device when I fire the system intent

Tags: android

When I fire the system intent, the Android device opens the wrong settings page. I tried to open the Data Roaming setting page with the below code, but the device opened the settings page in which data roaming option is not present.

```
if (bv < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
    intent.setComponent(cName);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: use this intent just change settings to networksetting

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

It's working in my case. This thing is working for me in android 4.1.2

Comment: @ashish read more about older version support very nice SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407818/error-opening-mobile-network-settings-menu)

Comment: problem is that android system handles the intents but opens wrong activity.